# How can I randomly display a single character from a given word

Tags: java, random, char

Here is an update as to where I am at and what I am stuck on based on what @camickr suggested. The issue that I am coming across now is that since I have to have a return statement at the end I can only return the ArrayList letters.

Also every time the hint button is pressed only one character appears in the solution location and it is [], yet no actual letters that make up the solution appear.

```
public String generateLetterHint(int count, String word) {

    String[] answerArray = word.split("");
    ArrayList<String> letters = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(answerArray));
    //StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
    Collections.shuffle(letters);

    while (!letters.isEmpty()) {
        String letter = letters.remove(0);
        System.out.println(letter);
    }
    return letters.toString();
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way it to add each (unique) letter of the String to an `ArrayList`.

Then you can use the `Collections.shuffle(...)` method to randomize the letters.

Each time the "Hint" button is pressed you:

1. get the letter at index 0
2. "remove" the letter from position 0
3. give the hint.

Now the next time the "Hint" button is clicked there will be a different letter at index 0.

Of course each time the user guesses a correct letter you would need to "remove" that letter from the ArrayList as well.

Edit:

Simple example showing proof of concept:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        String answer = "answer";

        String[] answerArray = answer.split("");
        ArrayList<String> letters = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(answerArray));

        Collections.shuffle( letters );

        while (!letters.isEmpty())
        {
            String letter = letters.remove(0);
            System.out.println(letter);
        }
    }
}
```

In you real code you would only create the ArrayList once and do the shuffle once when you determine what the "answer" word is.

Then every time you need a hint you can simply invoke a method that does:

```
public String getHint(ArrayList letters)
{
    return (letters.isEmpty() ? "" : letters.remove(0);
}
```

This will simply return an empty string if there are no more hints. Although a better solution would be to disable the hint button once the hints are finished.

Comment: When you say that I remove the letter from position 0 then give the hint, would it also be possible to give letter at a position other than 0?

Comment: @SOEN_student, You miss the point. You stated you want to give a "random" hint. After "shuffling" the ArrayList, the first letter will be a random letter.

Comment: what I was trying to ask was that if I use an ArrayList as well as Collections would it be possible to get a a letter at random that makes up the answer instead of taking the letter at index 0?

Comment: @SOEN_student, Why don't you want the letter at index 0? **The letter at index 0 is a random letter!!!**  Do you know how to "shuffle" a deck of cards? After you shuffle, each time you take a card from the top it will be a different card. Same with this suggestion. You do the shuffle once. Now each time you get (and remove) the letter at index 0 you get a random letter. Did you even try the suggestion? Did you get random letters?

Comment: I tried what you said and the output that I am getting is this [] each time I press the hint button. I followed what you said with getting the letter at the index 0 then remove that letter from the position and give the hint and placed it all inside of the for loop with the nested if-statement to only give hints up to the maximum number of characters in the answer. 
    `if (i <= count - 1){
                Collections.shuffle(letters);
                letters.add(0, word.charAt(0));
                letters.remove(0);
                string.append(letters);
            }`

Comment: @SOEN_student, Not sure why you are talking about a for loop. There would be no looping code in your actual solution. Your question is about providing a hint. So each time you click a button you will get a letter that can be used as a hint. See edit to answer for proof of concept. The example only uses a for loop to show that each time you get the letter at index 0, it will be a different letter (hint). The order of hints will be different each time you run the class.

Comment: If you need more help then post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates what you are doing. So you would need a JFrame and a "Hint" button. When you click the button the hint will be displayed. Don't post code in a comment. The code is not readable and the context of how the code is used is not apparent.

Answer (score 0):

Its working for only one answer. You can modify then work with multiple answer at the same time. When you you send a string to function, it gives you a letter that is unique inside from the string.

```
package com.Stackoverflow;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomlyString {
    private static List<Character> selectableLetters;   // it store randomly selectable letters
    private static boolean isFirst = true;

    private static char letterHint(String answer) {
        Random rnd = new Random();

        // when function starts in first time, split the string letter by letter
        if (isFirst) {
            selectableLetters = splitString(answer);
        }
        isFirst = false;

        if(!selectableLetters.isEmpty()) {
            int hintIndex = rnd.nextInt(selectableLetters.size());  // select a letter randomly
            char hint = selectableLetters.get(hintIndex);   // put this letter to hint
            selectableLetters.remove(hintIndex);    // then remove this letter from selectableLetters, this is for don't select the same letter twice
            return hint;
        } else {
            System.out.println("There is no hint!");
            return ' ';
        }
    }

    private static List<Character> splitString(String string) {
        List<Character> chars = new ArrayList<>();

        // split the string to letters and add to chars
        for (char c: string.toCharArray()) {
            chars.add(c);
        }
        return chars;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String answer = "Monkey";

        for(int i=0; i<7; i++) {
            System.out.println("Hints: " + letterHint(answer)); // it writes hint to screen
            System.out.println("Other letters: " + selectableLetters);  // currently selectable letters for hint
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to your answer.

Comment: @SOEN_student, `Thanks! It works,` - then don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark so people know the problem has been solved. Of course my suggestion does the same thing. I just don't believe in "spoon feeding" answers. `I was just wondering if you know how to... ` because once you start spoon feeding the OP just keeps asking for more code instead of understanding the suggestion and applying the knowledge to solve the problem.